# Checking if a user is clocked in or out

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table of employees which holds basic information like forename, lastname etc.. Each employee is given a unique ID.

I then have two tables, `rwh_clock_in` and `rwh_clock_out` which both look like this:

```
id (int) 255 PRIMARY A_I
atTime (timestamp) DEFAULT_TIMESTAMP
userid (int) 255
```

I am trying to select the users information from the database and then also check if the user is clocked in or clocked out.

```
SELECT employee.forename, employee.surname, employee.contactNumber, employee.contactEmail
(CASE WHEN clockin.atTime > clockout.atTime THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) AS 'clockedIn'
FROM rwh_employers employee
LEFT JOIN rwh_clock_in clockin
ON employee.id = employee.id AND employee.id = clockin.userid
LEFT JOIN rwh_clock_out clockout
ON employee.id = employee.id AND employee.id = clockout.userid AND clockin.userid = clockout.userid
WHERE employee.id = 1
```

However, I receive an SQL error that reads:

> 1305 - FUNCTION employee.contactEmail does not exist

My `rwh_employers` table does in fact have a `contactEmail` column that is VARCHAR (120).

I thought about it logically, I won't know if the user has clocked out or not if I do not check if there is any rows that is after the `atTime` from the `rwh_clock_in` in the `rwh_clock_out`. So, I need to firstly check for any clock outs from that userid after the clock in times. If it exists then the user is not clocked in, if it doesn't then the user is clocked in.

Any help would be appreciated.

**UPDATE:**

```
SELECT employee.forename, employee.surname, employee.contactNumber, employee.contactEmail, clockin.atTime,
(CASE WHEN clockin.atTime < clockout.atTime THEN clockout.atTime ELSE NULL END) AS 'clockOut'
FROM rwh_employers employee
LEFT JOIN rwh_clock_in clockin
ON employee.id = employee.id AND employee.id = clockin.userid
LEFT JOIN rwh_clock_out clockout
ON employee.id = employee.id AND employee.id = clockout.userid AND clockin.userid = clockout.userid
WHERE employee.id = 1
ORDER BY clockout.atTime ASC LIMIT 1
```

Now, the `clockout` is always NULL even when the user is clocked out

Comment: missing comma (`,`) after employee.contactEmail.. it should be `employee.contactEmail, 
(CASE WHEN clockin.atTime > clockout.atTime THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) AS 'clockedIn'`

Comment: You need to separate contactEmail and the parentheses, or it will be considered a function.

Comment: I didn't see that at all, it works when I add the `,` and change the `>` to a `<` but I don't think it will work on multiple records since I'm not ordering the dates or checking if a clockout exists

Comment: locked or clocked?

Comment: Either way, I would strongly encourage you to have only one table, with a column to determine whether the user clocked in or out.

Comment: I need records of when the user clocked in and out to work out the amount of hours @Strawberry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to want the latest time for a given user from each table.  I would suggest something more along these lines:

```
select cio.user_id,
       (case when last_ci < last_co then 'checked_out'
             else 'checked_in'
        end) as which
from (select 1 as user_id,
             (select max(atTime) from rwh_clock_in where user_id = 1) as last_ci,
             (select max(atTime) from rwh_clock_ou where user_id = 1) as last_co
     ) cio;
```

Comment: I get an error cio.userid doesn't exist in fieldtable and userid doesn't exist in fieldtable